# @mysql/xdevapi returning invalid input expression when inserting data (MySQL 8)

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using the [@mysql/xdevapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mysql/xdevapi) package with NodeJS and the [MySQL 8 docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/mysql/).

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error: invalid input expression
    at module.exports (C:\Users\BugHunter\Projects\nines\server\node_modules\@mysql\xdevapi\lib\DevAPI\Util\parseFlexibleParamList.js:43:15)
```

Here's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `surveyrewards`.`users` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `surname` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `birthday` DATE NULL,
  `gender` ENUM("male", "female") NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `postcode` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `is_subscribed` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `is_confirmed` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `last_mailed` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And my node code [using these docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/devapi-users-working-with-relational-tables.html):

```
require('dotenv').config()

const mysqlx = require('@mysql/xdevapi')

const config = {
  host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST ,
  user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  port: parseInt(process.env.MYSQL_PORT),
  password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  schema: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE
}
mysqlx.getSession(config)
.then(session => {
  console.log(process.env)
  const table = session.getSchema(config.schema).getTable('users')
  return table
    .insert([ 'firstname', 'surname', 'email', 'gender', 'is_subscribed', 'is_confirmed' ])
    .values('Bob', 'hope', 'bob@example.com', 'male', 0, 0)
    .execute()
})
.then(() => console.log('Works'))
.catch(err => console.warn(err))
```

The error is vauge and I'm not sure how to progress from here as my code is the same. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is actually a bug, which is why the error message is not clear. :)

Falsy values such as `0` are not currently accepted as valid `values()` arguments. This should not be the case though. If you feel like it, you can report it via the [MySQL bug tracker](https://bugs.mysql.com/) using the `Connector for Node.js` category, but you can consider this as being tracked.

One sort of nasty workaround is to use strings instead. Even if the SQL datatype is `TINYINT` like in your case, it will still work and the value will be "coerced".

```
return table
  .insert([ 'firstname', 'surname', 'email', 'gender', 'is_subscribed', 'is_confirmed' ])
  .values('Bob', 'hope', 'bob@example.com', 'male', '0', '0')
  .execute()
```

Disclaimer: I'm the lead dev of the connector.

Comment: Thank you. I spent hours trying to figure this out. Regarding date types is it fine to just use `new Date(somedate)`? If I get some time I may take a look into the library if it's an issue that's occurring with the node lib.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for bringing this up as well. Regarding dates, right now, you have to "stringify" them first using a valid [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html) date format.